# Is there a guarantee that AsyncCallbacks will always execute on the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Exactly what the question says.

I've read the MSDN article given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback(v=vs.110).aspx), and (unless I'm blind), can't see anywhere where it explicity confirms this.

To give more scope, I'm mainly referring to the `Socket.Beginxxx` methods provided in the `Socket` class.

Is it safe for me to assume that any AsyncCallbacks will be executed in the main thread?  Assume any `Socket.Beginxxx` methods I call will also be called from the main thread.

EDIT: If this is not the case, should I `lock` private members of the containing class when I modify them in one of the `Socket.Beginxxx` AsyncCallbacks?  E.g. adding an item to a dictionary?

Comment: No. It's not safe to make this blanket assumption. Certainly in a UI thread and when handling requests in ASP.net applications, your continuation will be marshalled back to the originating context, but in console applications (and probably several other environments that I haven't thought of), no such guarantee is made.

Comment: And this is because why?

Comment: Take a read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've read the MSDN article given here, and (unless I'm blind), can't see anywhere where it explicity confirms this.

The relevant quote is (emphasis added):

> Use an AsyncCallback delegate to process the results of an asynchronous operation **in a separate thread**.

The callback is *not* guaranteed to execute in the originating thread; in fact, it is guaranteed to run on *another* thread (i.e., a thread pool thread).

In spite of the other answers, this has absolutely nothing to do with `SynchronizationContext` or how [TAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) or [EAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx) work with their contexts. `AsyncCallback` is part of [APM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) - the oldest asynchronous pattern - which does absolutely no automatic thread marshaling for you.

> If this is not the case, should I lock private members of the containing class when I modify them in one of the Socket.Beginxxx AsyncCallbacks? E.g. adding an item to a dictionary?

You could. I have found in my asynchronous socket code that it's easier to marshal all the callbacks back to a single shared thread which is responsible for all socket operations and related data. Then no locks are necessary because all the "completed events" are synchronized to a single thread.

Comment: I didn't notice this at all, my mistake.  Do you think using your method is any more efficient than using locks?  If so, any chance of an example on how you did this?  Threading is not my strong suit.

Comment: @LukePark: If at all possible, I'd recommend using SignalR instead of raw sockets. But if you do use raw sockets, you can use `SynchronizationContext.Post` to notify the main thread of socket events, or use my `ClientTcpSocket` class from [this somewhat dated library](https://nitoasync.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

No. Your assumption does not always hold. Some frameworks may override the override the synchronization context to invoke continuations on a specific thread, but there is no guarantee at language-level. Here's what Stephen Toub says about it (in a [very informative post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx) on the subject):

> frameworks can derive their own context from SynchronizationContext and override the Post method to be more appropriate to the scheduler being represented. In the case of Windows Forms, for example, the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext implements Post to pass the delegate off to Control.BeginInvoke. For DispatcherSynchronizationContext in WPF, it calls to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. And so on.... That’s how await “brings you back to where you were.”

With an unchanged SychronizationContext (such as with a console app), the continuations will be queued to the ThreadPool, and so effectively, it could run on any thread.